# Amazon Elastic IP + EC2

Tags: dns, amazon-ec2

I have set up an EC2 instance and an Elastic IP which is associated to the instance. I have also set an A record in my DNS provider's Zone editor so that the domain name points to the elastic IP e.g. example.com = 123.123.123.123.

After reading many posts, this seems like it should be enough to work but my domain name still isn't resolving. I can't even ping the IP address! Weirdly I CAN ssh into the EC2 instance via the elastic IP and everything seems fine, except that my domain name doesn't resolve to the EC2 instance!

Any thoughts?

Comment: Lot sof possibilities: Stale DNS, wrong IP in the DNS, firewall rules.

Comment: Dont forget to upvote answers if you accept them. Its weird that you accept the answer and dont find it worth while to upvote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DNS names take a while to propagate so that is probably your first issue.

1. Go to http://www.whatsmydns.net/ and enter your domain name. If all of the locations are returning with the correct ip then you can safely assume its not a DNS propagation issue.
2. Enable ICMP rules in the security group. If using the aws console create a new rule for "All ICMP" with a source of "0.0.0.0/0". Enabling this creates a security risk for your server so only enable this temporarily while testing. At this point you should be able to ping your instance.
3. If using HTTP or HTTPS enable the correct ports on the security group for those protocols and as long as the instance is configured correctly with Apache you should be up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your EC2 security group & make sure desired ports are open